# change item from RecyclerView out of onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

On my `onBindViewHolder` I have this to set the `setImageResource`

```
holder.card_image.setImageResource(image);
```

But my items can be purchased so, I have this to purchase on my `holder.view.setOnClickListener()`

```
 bp.purchase((Activity) mContext,model.getProduct_id());
```

so, it goes to this method :

```
bp = new BillingProcessor() new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
                showToast("onProductPurchased: " + productId);
                //Purchased OK
                //WANT TO CHANGE THE IMAGE ONCE PURCHASE IS OK


            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
                showToast("onBillingError: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingInitialized() {
                showToast("onBillingInitialized");
                readyToPurchase = true;

            }
            @Override
            public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                showToast("onPurchaseHistoryRestored");
                for(String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                    Log.d("skuProducts", "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
                for(String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                    Log.d("skuProducts", "Owned Subscription: " + sku);

            }
        });
```

How do I change it if I'm not `onBindViewHolder`?

My adapter looks like :

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter< CardPOJO, CardHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            //inflate the single recycler view layout(item)
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_product, parent, false);
            int width = parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            width -= mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._8sdp);
            final CardHolder cardViewHolder = new CardHolder(view,width);
            return cardViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            tv.setVisibility(getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(CardHolder holder, int position, final CardPOJO model) {
            holder.state.setText(model.getState());
            holder.cardName.setText(model.getName());
            switch (model.getState()){
                case "free":
                    //Img free
                    break;
                case "not_free":
                    //Img not free
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(model.getState().equals("free")){
                       //stuff
                    }
                    else{
                       //stuff
                        }
                        root_ref.child("PurchasedProducts").child(currentuser).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                bp.purchase((Activity) mContext,model.getProduct_id()); //HERE I CALL THE PURCHASE SO IF IT'S OK I WANT TO DO SOMETHING LIKE holder.card_image.setImageResource(image);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });


        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    products_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I assume correctly you want to change the view appearance or some image change if some payment is done successful or failed.

for that, you can have a **callback** which will give you the item position in activity or fragment back from there you can make a server call to make the purchase happen and if everything goes well.

when you make your adapter constructor pass the callback

```
final SomeAdapter obj = new SomeAdapter(this,new Callback(){
      @Override
      onPaymentRequested(int position, View view){
        //this will get called when you press click on image in bindviewholder
        bp = new BillingProcessor() new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
                showToast("onProductPurchased: " + productId);
                //Purchased OK
                adapterModelList.get(position).setPayment(true);
                obj.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
                showToast("onBillingError: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingInitialized() {
                showToast("onBillingInitialized");
                readyToPurchase = true;

            }
            @Override
            public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                showToast("onPurchaseHistoryRestored");
                for(String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts())
                    Log.d("skuProducts", "Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
                for(String sku : bp.listOwnedSubscriptions())
                    Log.d("skuProducts", "Owned Subscription: " + sku);

            }
        });

    }
    });
recyclerView.setAdapter(obj);
```

so when you call your **obj.notifyDataSetChanged();** it will make the adapter to draw all views again where you can set some flag according to int position  recieved for click callback and make it change accordingly.

**Edit=>07/12/2018**: Tried the Firebase Adapter and made few changes since the code was not enough to replicate the scenario but I have made a sample class made few changes but the basic idea is like below.

1: When user click on view in onBindViewHolder we receive a callback which gives a position parameter in fragment or activity from where we are calling

2: Now we process the payment and when we are done we make a change in Database firebase also by updating the CardPojo to server for that particular user item.

3: while we update the CardPojo on server we also set a flag in card pojo which is a boolean for paymentSuccess which will be true when payment is done.

4: since our payment is done and is synced with server with new flag data now we can just call `firebaseRecycler.notifyItemChanged(position);` which will get the lates update from the server for that particular position which we have received on callback.

5: Now populateViewHolder() gives you a cardpojo object you can check if payment is done then you can change the image

so here is the sample code involved I have tried to match the scenario at best, hope you understand what I am trying to do here.

so first create a listener or a callback

```
public interface CallBackInterface  {
    void onClick(int position,CardPOJO cardPOJO);
}
```

now instead of initializing the **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter** in activity or fragment just create a class and extend it this separates your ui logic and gives us the extensibility of doing extra things like adding callback.

```
public class FirebaseRecycler extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CardPOJO,CardHolder> {

CallBackInterface callBackInterface;

public FirebaseRecycler(Class<CardPOJO> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<CardHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    this.callBackInterface = callBackInterface;
}

public FirebaseRecycler(Class<CardPOJO> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<CardHolder> viewHolderClass, Query ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    this.callBackInterface = callBackInterface;
}

@Override
public CardHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //your inflater logic goes here
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_product, parent, false);
    CardHolder cardHolder = new CardHolder(view);
    return cardHolder;
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(CardHolder viewHolder, final CardPOJO model, final int position) {
    //your populate logic
    //your existing code here

    if (model.isPaymentDone){
        //set payment success image holder.card_image.setImageResource(image);

    }else{
        //set payment failure image

    }

    //setting the card click listener
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //we have the card click listener, we will start the payment processing in activity
            callBackInterface.onClick(position,model);
        }
    });
}

public void setCallBackInterface(CallBackInterface callBackInterface) {
    this.callBackInterface = callBackInterface;
}
```

}

now almost everything is done we need to call this Custom Firebase adapter and pass the required things and it will do its job.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    /*
    if you have any other database child then you can refer to it using
    DatabaseReference child = mDatabaseRef.child("yourchilddatabase");
    and pass this to the last argument
     */

    final FirebaseRecycler firebaseRecycler = new FirebaseRecycler(CardPOJO.class, R.layout.card_product, CardHolder.class, mDatabaseRef);
    firebaseRecycler.setCallBackInterface(new CallBackInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final int position, final CardPOJO cardPOJO) {
            //start processing the payment

            bp = new BillingProcessor() new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {
                    /**
                     *when you have processed the payment just enable the flag on server database by having a extra boolean flag for this
                     * and check in onBindViewHolder if this is enabled if so then replace your image
                     * updating the values on server, you can handle it according to your user case
                     */
                    cardPOJO.setPaymentDone(true);
                    mDatabaseRef.push().setValue(cardPOJO);
                    firebaseRecycler.notifyItemChanged(position);

                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {
                    //existing logic
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingInitialized() {
                    //existing logic
                }

                @Override
                public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
                    //existing logic
                }
            };

        }
    });

}
```

this demonstrates the basic logic you can patch it according to your requirement.

Comment: I thought about callBack() but didn't know how to integrate in Android, well.. where do I have to put the callback? what is someAdapter? my adapteR?

Comment: if you can paste your adapter code then i can help you other wise i will create a dummy adapter to show the process let me know.

Comment: sorry @Stuart2041 im not familiar with firebase adapter so can't help, i thought you were using recyclerview adapter

Comment: it extends RecyclerView and RecyclerView adapter it's almost the same imo

Comment: okay let me have a revisit, if possible can you post your fragment or activity in which you are using firebase ui adapter and the adapter class related to this issue. i will create a dummy project and with your code and make the necessary changes. here you can post the code or give me a attachment link.

Comment: hi @Stuart2041 I have added a sample code according to your mock requirement hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea separate the Adapter, i know it's better, but I use different stuff of the Activity let me try without creating that new class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162692/discussion-between-stuart2041-and-vikas-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Get your item from `RecyclerView`'s adapter and edit it. Then just call `Adapter.onItemChanged(int position)`, this will cause to call `onBindViewholder` to be called specifically for that position.

Comment: can you put an example? I don't get it a little bit of code pseudo if you want but I don't get you